# selected dropdown list value changes after page reload

Tags: jquery

I have a `dropdown` list in my application's layout . So in every page it is visible . In the `dropdown` list I have a list of hotels , when I change a hotel in `dropdown` , it redirects to the main page , with the changed `id` , it works fine , but the problem is when reloading the page , `selected` `dropdown` value is reset , how can i keep the selected value with out changing? . :(

Comment: i am using zend framework ......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need to store its state somewhere, perhaps in a cookie.

Then on page load, you'd need to retrieve its state on load.

Comment: yeah i stored current value in a seesion and passed to the form when creating the form thanksssssss